# Does the final scene of A New Hope take place on Yavin IV?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Does the medal ceremony scene at the end of A New Hope take place on Yavin IV?  Shouldn't the Rebels be evacuating instead of handing out medals? Even though they destroyed the death star the rest of the empire surely knows they are there.

Comment: This is addressed in the dupe. They're in the middle of evacuating when they have the ceremony. It's a brief one, then they start loading up the ships again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [the Royal Award Ceremony](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_Award_Ceremony) did take place on Yavin 4, the morning after the Battle of Yavin.

According to the canon comic *Princess Leia*, they couldn't evacuate until other Rebel ships arrived to help.

[image]